# React hooks state does not update after deleting

Tags: reactjs, state

So my state does not update immediatly after deleting an item. I have tried to filter games inside of onDelete. Like setGames(games.filter(game => game.urlSlug !== urlSlug)) but with no success.Does anyone have any ideas? :)

```
const [games, setGames] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getGames();
}, [])

const getGames = async () => {
  await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/admin/games')
  .then((result) => {
    result.json().then((resp) => {
      setGames(resp)
    })
  })
}

const onDelete = async (urlSlug) => {
  await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/admin/games/${urlSlug}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).then((res) => {
    res.json().then((data) => {
     getGames();
    })
  })
```

[][1]

This is my backend in node.js

router.delete("/games/:urlslug", async (req, res, next)  => {

```
const {urlslug} = req.params;
const db = req.app.locals.db;

try {

const sql = `
DELETE FROM game WHERE urlslug = $1
`;

await db.query(sql, [urlslug])
// res.status(404).send();
return true;

}
catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
  return false;
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for much VladSofronov! It was my backend that was wrong. I fixed it :)

router.delete("/games/:urlslug", async (req, res, next)  => {

```
const {urlslug} = req.params;
const db = req.app.locals.db;

try {

const sql = `
DELETE FROM game WHERE urlslug = $1
`;

await db.query(sql, [urlslug])
res.status(204).send();
res.json(urlslug)
return true;

}
catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
  return false;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your API gets updated after you hit it up? If you `console.log(data)` before `getGames()` does it return without the element you are trying to remove?

As for filtering the state the correct way would probably be something like `setGames(prevGames => prevGames.filter(game => game.urlSlug !== urlSlug)}`

Comment: I see! I tried to console.log the data. And got nothing back. That's a bad sign! Gonna post my backend code here aswell :)

Comment: That's the culprit then probably. Because the code you've posted should work in theory as it is.

Comment: It does delete it tho. But i have to update the page :(

Comment: I have updated my post. So now there is backend in there aswell